# MongoDB max in group results

Tags: mongodb, max, aggregation-framework

I grouped results by `mvid` and the counted number of occurrences in each group.

```
db.some_details.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$mvid", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Now, I would like to select group with max count. Here is my naive guess:

```
db.some_details.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$mvid", count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$max: "count"}
])
```

It, obviously, generates an error. I need to use max with group, but I don't have anything to group on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What also would work is sorting the result and then using only the first element:

```
db.some_details.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$mvid", count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$sort: {"count": -1}},
{$limit: 1 }
])
```

The advantage that I see compared to chridam's solution is that you also get the id of the group with the maximum count, but I expect it to be slower (not tested).

Answer (score 4):

The aggregation pipeline allows you to could include another [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator pipeline that would give you the maximum count of all the groups:

```
db.some_details.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$mvid", 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 0, 
            maxCount: { $max: "$count" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This is a great solution, except it does not return `mvid` with max count.